# Isnt using a method of a seperate class considered abstraction

Tags: java, abstraction

When calling a method from another class is it considered abstraction? Because when the `main` method creates the `Dog` object and uses the method `animalSound`, the user cannot see what is being done. Is this considered abstraction?

Dog.java

```
public class Dog {
    public void animalSound() {
         System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.animalSound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take care of proper formatting of the code parts. Also - what abstraction is - is easy to find on google. Question should only be asked after at least quick investigation. Concerning the content: that is just a CALL. Abstraction comes into play when you are using inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

> When calling a method from another class is it considered abstraction?

Abstraction (in computer science) means hiding details.

So you are essentially asking whether a method *call* is abstracting (hiding) the details of the method.

The strict answer is No.  The details of what the method does are being hidden by the method *declaration* not by the method *call*.

However, in the more general sense, it is true that methods are a form of abstraction.

---

By the way, a commentator said this:

> Abstraction comes into play when you are using inheritance.

This is not correct.

1. Data abstraction does not require inheritance.  In fact, the classical definition of a (staticly) object oriented language is that it supports "inheritance + data abstraction (or encapsulation) + polymorphism".  Inheritance and data abstraction are orthogonal properties.
2. There are examples of programming languages that support data abstraction without inheritance.  For instance, CLU and (depending on how strict you are<sup>1</sup>) Ada83.
3. Data abstraction is not the only kind of abstraction.  Other kinds include:

   - Procedural abstraction; i.e. procedures, functions, subroutines, etcetera.  In procedural abstraction, we are hiding just algorithmic details.
   - Modularisation which hides larger scale details of some part of an application.

See the Wikipedia page on [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) for more details.

---

<sup>1 - In Ada83, a subtype cannot add new fields or override existing methods ("operations").  See http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/dale/ada/aln/14_OO.html</sup>